# Extract every value from a complex JSON into an array in Swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary, flatten

My client is returning an insane JSON when the backend find an error. It includes many "errors" keys along an indeterminate number of arrays and nested sections of the JSON. Here is an example:

```
{
 "errors": {
    "children": {
      "name": {
        "errors": [
          "Error name"
        ]
      },
      "lastName": {
        "errors": [
          "Error lastName"
        ]
      },
      "email": {
        "errors": [
          "Error mail"
        ]
      },
      "gender": {},
      "birthday": {
        "children": {
          "year": {},
          "month": {
            "errors": [
              "Error month"
             ]
          },
          "day": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since he claims the response can't be rewritten to return a more conventional error handling, I'd like to iterate through the JSON and get an array with every error string. Given that there's no other value but errors, I think getting all the values will do the trick too. The JSON structure may change according the error location and the service.

I'm currently using SwiftyJSON to parse the response (in case it may be of any help)

Comment: without knowing the key value how you will able to find data , json root value may be dictionary or array , you can use this to check

Comment: Yes Shobhakar, I knew that and I did a recursive fuction that iterated through the json tree but I didn't find the way to return the final result. iWheelBuy and Benzi have posted two valid different approaches to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a recursive function that attempts to filter out error messages from its input.

Since your JSON structure is not well defined, you need to conditionally type and check your root / current object as an array or a dictionary.

The following is sample code that can be run in an XCode Playground.

```
func extractErrors(jsonObject: Any, errors: inout [String]) {
    if let array = jsonObject as? [Any] {
        array.forEach {
            extractErrors(jsonObject: $0, errors: &errors)
        }
    }
    else if let dict = jsonObject as? [String : Any] {
        for key in dict.keys {
            if key == "errors", let errorList = dict[key] as? [String] {
                errorList.forEach { errors.append($0) }
            }
            else {
                extractErrors(jsonObject: dict[key]!, errors: &errors)
            }
        }
    }
}

let json = "{\"errors\":{\"children\":{\"name\":{\"errors\":[\"Error name\"]},\"lastName\":{\"errors\":[\"Error lastName\"]},\"email\":{\"errors\":[\"Error mail\"]},\"gender\":{},\"birthday\":{\"children\":{\"year\":{},\"month\":{\"errors\":[\"Error month\"]},\"day\":{}}}}}}"

if let data = json.data(using: .utf8),
    let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.mutableContainers])
{
    var errors = [String]()
    extractErrors(jsonObject: jsonObject, errors: &errors)
    print(errors) // ["Error lastName", "Error name", "Error mail", "Error month"]

}
```

Comment: Thank you. The previous answer is correct but I think this is a more elegant way to resolve this problem so I'll check it for future visitors. I had already done something very similar but I was trying to use the inout var wrong. With your help I've learned that too.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have some data

```
let data: Data = /* the way you get your JSON data */
```

You expect to have some function that extracts all error messages from JSON and put them into an array `[String]`, don't you? I see 4 errors in your JSON, so lets do the function that will find all 4 messages:

```
func getErrors(_ dictionary: [String:JSON]?) -> [String] {
    guard let dictionary = dictionary else { return [] }
    let errorsNormal = dictionary
        .map({ (object) -> [String] in
            guard object.key == "errors" else { return [] }
            guard let array = object.value.array else { return [] }
            return  array.flatMap({ $0.string })
        })
        .flatMap({ $0 })
    let errorsRecursive = dictionary
        .flatMap({ (object) -> [String:JSON]? in
            return object.value.dictionary
        })
        .flatMap({ $0 })
        .map({ getErrors($0) })
        .flatMap({ $0 })
    return errorsNormal + errorsRecursive
}
```

How to use?

```
let errors = getErrors(json["errors"].dictionary)
debugPrint(errors)
```

The log will be

```
["Error lastName", "Error name", "Error mail", "Error month"]
```

P.S. If it's not what you want - please let me know and I'll remove the answer

Comment: In fact. This is exactly what I want. Thank you.